# Marcar checkbox respecto a mi base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Buen dia,

Estoy tratando de marcar unos checkbox con jquery con respecto a mi base de datos. Estoy usando Ajax para recibir los valores que deben estar marcados en los checkbox.

intente hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero no me ha funcionado.

Yo recibo la respuesta de fetch_permisos.php un arreglo que contiene una cadena con la siguiente informacion: "usuarios,registros,roles"  <--- donde esto me dice los checkbox que deben estar marcados.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "fetch_permisos.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
    
    let options = data.permisos.split(',');

    for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++)
    {
      $("[name='opt[]']").eq(options[i]).prop("checked",true);
      
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="usuarios"> Ver usuarios
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="registros"> Ver registros
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="roles"> Ver roles
```

Comment: Necesitamos ver el resultado de un `console.log(data);` para ver cómo están estructurados los datos que estás recibiendo.

Comment: @A.Cedano esto es lo que me da de salida por consola   {permisos: 'usuarios,registros,roles'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casi lo tenías, debes incluir el valor en el filtro de los atributos, pruebalo así:

```js
let permisos = "usuarios,roles"; //En tu caso es el valor de data.permisos
let options = permisos.split(',');

for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
      $(`[name='opt[]'][value='${options[i]}']`).prop("checked",true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="usuarios"> Ver usuarios
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="registros"> Ver registros
<input type="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="roles"> Ver roles
```

Comment: muchas gracias.. si me funciono :D